# How to justify Text in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

hi i want to know how to justify paragraph in Crystal report .

In justify paragraph by using below method but it only justify the first row while other rows remain unjustified.

```
Right click on field > Format Object > Common Tab> Horizontal alignment > justify.
```

but it only justify the first row nor the entire report.

Please help

Comment: first row means, first row in a field?

Answer (score 0):

Right button click on an object and select ***Format Object***. Set Justify on Horizontal alignment in Paragraph Tab

[image]